# Component class variable from HTTP promise is undefined when interpolated on template

Tags: angular, typescript, es6-promise

I have a promise returning an object from my service

```
export class mma {
 age: number;
 name: string;
}
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getMessage(): Promise<mma> {
return this.http.get('/map-moving-agents')
           .toPromise()
           .then((res)=> {
             console.log(res.json().obj);
              return res.json().obj;
            })
           .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and i have a component class method that assigns the returned promise object to a component class/instance variable that i would like to interpolate in my component template

```
export class mma {
 age: number;
 name: string;
}
@Component({
 moduleId:module.id,
 selector: 'map-moving-agents',
 template: '<p>{{msg.name}}</p>',
 providers: [ MyService ]
})

export class MapMovingAgents implements OnInit{

 msg : mma;

constructor(private myService: MyService ){}
getMessage(): void {
    this.myService.getMessage().then((res) => {     
         this.msg = res;
         console.log(this.msg.name);  
        })

}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessage();
}
}
```

I have logged the 'this.msg' in 'getMessage' and the promise 'then' but when i interpolate it, 'msg' like {{msg.name}} i get and error saying cannot read property 'name' of undefined,
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the safe-navigation operator to avoid errors when Angular resolves the binding before the value becomes available:

```
template: '<p>{{msg?.name}}</p>',
```

Comment: Always the fastest :P

Comment: Lots of practice ;-) Thanks for fixing the typo!

Comment: Yes.. it did resolve, :D, thanks guys, so i can look up **safe-navigator operator** so that i can understand it better and know when to use it, am i correct?

Comment: All it does is that `.name` is not evaluated when `msg` is null. It's a bit more complicated if the expression is longer. You need to repeat it for `msg?.name?.given` or `msg?.name?.fullName()`. It does **not** support `[]` like `msg?.nameParts?[1]` (invalid).

Comment: The operator has many names (Elvis, null coalescing, safe-navigation, and probably others) See also https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16

Comment: Okay so ' It does not support [] like msg?.nameParts?[1]', then how would i get only one element in 'nameParts' if it was an array and a key of msg?

Comment: You need a more elaborate syntax like `msg?.nameParts?.length && msg.namParts[1]`. This way the part after `&&` is only evaluated if `msg.nameParts.length` > 1.

Comment: I meant `> 0` instead of `> 1` but I assume you got it :D

Answer (score 1):

`mma` should not a class defined twice it should be `interface`

```
interface  mma {
 age: number;
 name: string;
}
```

also remove `providers: [ MyService ]' from component which is creating multiple instances of service

Comment: I dont have `providers: [ MyService ]' in my root module, i only have it in that component

Comment: I will change the class to an interface thanks, that's good, but the actually issue has a working solution, read up.